# Restart kivy-program respectively python with inotify

Tags: python, bash, kivy, inotify

I fear that my question is a duplicate but I can't find the answer. Maybe you can help me?

I would like to restart my kivy-program if I save the kv or py file.

I tried with

```
inotifywait -mq -e close_write /home/name/kivy/ | while read FILE
do
  pkill python
  python /home/name/kivy/main.py
done
```

If I change a file the first time, main.py starts, but if I change it again I need to close the program by hand before it restarts.

Instead of pkill python I also tried to use

```
kill $(ps aux | pgrep '[p]ython' | awk '{print $2}')
```

but with the same result and the problem that the mintMenu.py is closing, too.

Should I use something totally different to inotify?

Comment: Better use a `&`: `python /home/name/kivy/main.py &`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [entr](http://entrproject.org/) to achieve the same thing. Once installed (e.g. via `brew`), just run the following command in your work directory `/home/name/kivy/`:

```
find . -name "*.py" -or -name "*.kv" | entr sh -c "pkill -f python main.py ; python main.py &"
```